# I'm trying to make multilang site "en & ar" with json but AR content comes out ltr, how can i make the AR comes out rtl and EN still ltr?

Tags: javascript, multilingual

this is the javascript code that i used o translate the site and i ve linked it with json files for the content

```
    var LanguageList = {

};


window.onload = initialize;

function initialize() {
  var $dropdown = $("#country_select");    
  $.each(LanguageList, function(key, value) {
    $dropdown.
      append($("<option/>").
      val(key).
      text(value));
    });
    
  loadsLanguage("EN");
}

function loadsLanguage(lang){
  $('span[class^="lang"]').each(function(){
    var LangVar = (this.className).replace('lang-','');
    var Text = window["WORDS_"+lang][LangVar];
    $(this).text(Text);        
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add in your HTML file

```
<html dir="auto" lang="AR">
   ...
</html>
```

or in every `span`

```
<span dir="auto">
   ...
</span>
```

and make sure that you are updating the text

Comment: didn't work!
all the elements now are getting right even in English and some are missed up!